# Failed to invoke public android.app.Service() with no args

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit

When I try to get data from API retrofit response failed only when **service** **Array** have data if it null response is Successful and have other all data but when the   **service** **Array** have data retrofit on failure method give this message: `Failed to invoke public android.app.Service() with no args`

First time working with retrofit and stuck here and tired help please Thanks in Advance

When **Service Array** Have Data in JSON **getting Error**

```
 {
    id: 1,
    profile_image: "post_images/1594969413profile.jpg",
    firstname: "bilawal",
    lastname: "jabbar",
    address: "Sansfrasico",

    blog: [
    {
    id: 1,
    artist_profile_id: 1,
    title: "dsd",
    description: "sdsd",
    photo: "http://ec2-54-161-107-128.compute-1.server.com/post_images/1594811497blog.jpg",
    likes: 0,
    created_at: "15/07/20",
    like_link: "http://ec2-54-161-107-128.compute-1.server.com/api/like_blog/2",
    artist_image: "http://ec2-54-161-10128.compute1.server.com/post_images/1594969413profile.jpg",
    single_blog_link: "http://ec2-54-161-107-128.compute-1.server.com/api/blog/2"
    }],

    services: [
    {
    name: "test",
    details: "asasasasas",
    feature_image: "http://ec2-54-161-107-128.comp1.server.com/post_images/1594987588feature.jpg",
    price: 2,
    price_type: "Iix",
    rating: "No Yet Rating"
    }]
    }
```

When Services Array Not Have Data in JSON **Work Smoothly NO Error**

```
{
id: 2,
profile_image: "no",
firstname: "Hamza",
lastname: "Dj Yo",
address: "no",

blog: [ ],

services: [ ]
}
```

**Service Class**

```
package com.example.djikon;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Service {
    
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("details")
        @Expose
        private String details;
        @SerializedName("feature_image")
        @Expose
        private String featureImage;
        @SerializedName("price")
        @Expose
        private Integer price;
        @SerializedName("price_type")
        @Expose
        private String priceType;
        @SerializedName("rating")
        @Expose
        private String rating;
    
        /**
         * No args constructor for use in serialization
         *
         */
        public Service() {
        }
    
    
        public Service(String name, String details, String featureImage, Integer price, String priceType, String rating) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.details = details;
            this.featureImage = featureImage;
            this.price = price;
            this.priceType = priceType;
            this.rating = rating;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public String getDetails() {
            return details;
        }
    
        public void setDetails(String details) {
            this.details = details;
        }
    
        public String getFeatureImage() {
            return featureImage;
        }
    
        public void setFeatureImage(String featureImage) {
            this.featureImage = featureImage;
        }
    
        public Integer getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    
        public void setPrice(Integer price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public String getPriceType() {
            return priceType;
        }
    
        public void setPriceType(String priceType) {
            this.priceType = priceType;
        }
    
        public String getRating() {
            return rating;
        }
    
        public void setRating(String rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }
    
    }
```

and Also Main Object Class if you need

```
package com.example.djikon;

import android.app.Service;



import java.util.List;


    public class DJProfileModel {
    
    
        private Integer id;
    
        private String profile_image;
    
        private String firstname;
    
        private String lastname;
    
        private String address;
    
        private List<Blog_Model> blog;
    
        private List<Service> services;
    
        /**
         * No args constructor for use in serialization
         *
         * @param body
         */
        public DJProfileModel(DJProfileModel body) {
        }
    
    
        public DJProfileModel(Integer id, String profileImage, String firstname, String lastname, String address, List<Blog_Model> blog, List<Service> services) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.profile_image = profileImage;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.address = address;
            this.blog = blog;
            this.services = services;
        }
    
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public String getProfile_image() {
            return profile_image;
        }
    
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
    
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
    
        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
    
        public List<Blog_Model> getBlog() {
            return blog;
        }
    
        public List<Service> getServices() {
            return services;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem when I was using the 'Here'[JSONCONVERT](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) Auto generate class. To solve it, I made my own class for this **Service Response Array**. Now it's working smoothly.

Here is the my handmade class:

```
package com.example.djikon;

public class model {
    private String name,
    details,
    feature_image,
    price_type,
    rating;

    private int price;

    public model(String name, String details, String feature_image, int price, String price_type, String rating) {
        this.name = name;
        this.details = details;
        this.feature_image = feature_image;
        this.price = price;
        this.price_type = price_type;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public String getFeature_image() {
        return feature_image;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getPrice_type() {
        return price_type;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
}
```